# Get local datetime from UTC time

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-server, converting, t-sql

One of the app is inserting date in UTC format (column `CreateDate`). When reporting from this table, I used a difference in hours between the inbuilt `GetUTCDate()` and `GetDate()` and added the same to the `CreateDate` column. I was hoping to not worry about the daylight time. Is this approach OK?

```
SELECT GetUTCDate()
SELECT GetDate()
DECLARE @DifferenceInHoursBetween INT
SELECT @DifferenceInHoursBetween = DATEDIFF(HH,GetUTCDate(), GETDATE())
SELECT  USER_ID, CreateDate AS [DateTime IN UTC], DATEADD(HOUR,@DifferenceInHoursBetween,CreateDate) AS [LocalDateTime] FROM EVENTLOG(nolock)
```

/*Tests*/

```
SELECT GetUTCDate() AS [UTCDateTime]
SELECT GetDate() AS [LocalDateTime]
DECLARE @DifferenceInHoursBetween INT
SELECT @DifferenceInHoursBetween = DATEDIFF(HH,GetUTCDate(), GETDATE())
SELECT @DifferenceInHoursBetween AS [Difference in Hours]
```

-- UTCDateTime

2019-01-22 16:34:46.943

--LocalDateTime

2019-01-22 08:34:46.943

-- Difference in hours
-8

Comment: good approach is to save the date in UTC

Comment: To be fair, if DST was your initial concern, your SQL is not working as intended.

Answer (score 1):

### Review

You don't need to calculate the difference from two temporary values `GetUTCDate` and `GETDATE`.

> ```
> SELECT @DifferenceInHoursBetween = DATEDIFF(HH,GetUTCDate(), GETDATE())
> ```

### Proposed Solution

Instead, you could apply the local time zone offset to the specified datetime.

```
SELECT  
    USER_ID, 
    CreateDate AS [DateTime IN UTC], 
    CONVERT(datetime, 
        SWITCHOFFSET(CONVERT(datetimeoffset, CreateDate), 
            DATENAME(TzOffset, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()))) AS [LocalDateTime] 
FROM EVENTLOG(nolock);
```

---

[Fiddle: SQL Server 2017](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=27b7cc4016dcabffeb7e4a32d0c25d3b)

[image]

---

#### Daylight Savings Time

Both methods, OP and solution don't take into account DST. And unfortunately, SQL Server does not come with a built-in conversion from DST. You'd have to make a function yourself. [More about DST in SQL Server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/28187/how-can-i-get-the-correct-offset-between-utc-and-local-times-for-a-date-that-is)